# Understanding the definition of the represention ring

Tags: representation-theory

In Fulton, Harris, "Representation Theory. A first Course" there's the following paragraph which I don't really understand:

> The representation ring $R(G)$ of a group $G$ is easy to define. First, as a group we just take $R(G)$ to be the free abelian group generated by all (isomorphism classes of) representations of $G$, and mod out the subgroup generated by elements of the form $V+W-(V\oplus W)$. Equivalently, given the statement of complete reducibility, we can just take all integral linear combinations $\sum a_i\cdot V_i$ of the irreducible representations $V_i$ of $G$; elements of $R(G)$ are corrrespondingly called *virtual representations.* The ring structure is then given simply by tensor product, defined on the generators of $R(G)$ and extended by linearity.

OK, let's start with the "free abelian group generated by … representations of $G$". Now from what I understand, a free group is generated from a set of groups by formally multiplying elements of different groups together. Here, the multiplication is obviously replaced by addition.

However, here's my first problem: While representations are of course groups under element multiplication, they are in general not abelian; also, it wouldn't work well with the addition notation; I think something different is meant. But then, the only notion of addition for representations I can see is the direct sum (point-wise adding the matrix representations will not give another representation, and is not even well-defined if the dimension of the representations is different). But the direct sum doesn't give rise to a group structure because there's no additive inverse. Also the fact that it is explicitly used alongside the "group addition" in the "mod out the subgroup" part indicates that it is not what is meant.

So either I have an incorrect understanding of what the "free abelian group" means, or I'm missing a way how to define sums of representations, and especially the *additive inverse* $-V$ of a representation.

So can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: The free abelian group generated by the representations is $\bigoplus_{[\rho]}\mathbb{Z}$, where $[\rho]$ is the equivalence class of the representation $\rho$. Then $3\cdot[\rho_1] + 5 \cdot[\rho_2] = 5\cdot[\rho_2] + 3\cdot[\rho_1]$.

Comment: Isn't the direct sum of representations given by blocking them on diagonals?

Comment: @rschwieb: we aren't taking the direct sum of the representations. We're taking the direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ *indexed* by the representations.

Comment: @celtschk: are you comfortable with the definition of the group ring? It's defined in a similar way: we take the free abelian group generated by symbols $g \in G$, one for each element of the group, except we don't mod out by anything. The important point is that you should regard the group $G$ here, and the set of representations in the construction of the representation ring, as just a set: for the moment, you're ignoring all of its other structure.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I didn't yet encounter the definition of the group ring. But I think I understand your explanation anyway. Thank you.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ahh that's interesting. I really don't recognize this, despite having read several introductions long ago. I do remember something about representations being generated by integral combinations of irreducible representations. Is that what this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Now from what I understand, a free group is generated from a set of groups by formally multiplying elements of different groups together. Here, the multiplication is obviously replaced by addition."

*This* is your first problem: that's really not the definition of a free group, even approximately.  (Maybe you're thinking of *free products* instead.)  A free group and a free abelian group are both associated to a perfectly naked **set** $S$.  The free abelian group on $S$ is easier to understand: you can look it up [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group).  One can consider the free abelian group on $S$ as the set of all finite formal combinations $\sum_{s \in S} a_s [s]$ with $a_s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a_s = 0$ for all but finitely many $s$.  The group operation is $\sum_{s \in S} a_s [s] + \sum_{s \in S} b_s [s] = \sum_{s \in S} (a_s + b_s) [s]$.  (If $S$ is finite, this is just the direct product of $\# S$ copies of the infinite cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}$.)

Since this definition is new to you, you should probably soak it in for a while before trying to understand the definition of the representation ring $R(G)$.

Comment: Thank you, I was indeed confusing it with the free product. So do I now understand correctly that the free abelian group in $S$ basically is a "vector space" with a basis vector for each element of $S$, except that instead of a field, $\mathbb Z$ is used as scalars?

Comment: @celtschk Yes, that's about it. One of the differences is that there are abelian groups that don't admit a basis, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer: Now you're confusing me again. So you say $\mathbb Z/2$ is a free abelian group, but doesn't admit a basis?

Comment: @celtschk No, it is not free, it is just an abelian group. You could say that "every vector space is free" (it admits a basis, assuming choice). In contrast not every abelian group is free.

Comment: @celtschk: Yes, you should think of a free abelian group as being like a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}$.  What Julian is saying is that if you have a commutative ring $R$ which is not a field -- like $\mathbb{Z}$ -- then there are other **modules** over that ring which are not simply direct sums of copies of the ring $R$.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer, Pete: Thank you for the explanations. I think I understand now.